# SVM subgradient-descent (Pegasos algorithm)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the **Pegasos** algorithm for large scale **SVM training**. I'm following the main paper [Pegasos](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf). Everything worked fine but the results are quite disappointing. The code:

```
% I have my data matrix (m x n) where m
% is the no. of samples and n is the 
% dimensionality.

% X(i) is i-th data vector
% Y(i) is class {-1,+1}

% I have 200 examples of dimensionality 2
% and data is linearly separable

W = zeros([n, 1]); % the weight vector

lambda = 1e-5; % the regularization param

T = 5000; % max iter
k = 100; % batch size

for t = 1 : T
% iterate T times

A = randperm(m, k); % choose random subset
                % of k data vector

eta_t = 1 / (lambda * t); % eta of the algo
                    % at iteration t

Ap = [];
for q = A % choose the examples which
           % satisfy the condition
    if (W*X(q)) * Y(q) < 1
        Ap = [Ap, q];
    end
end
clear A;

temp = 0;
for q = Ap
    temp = temp + X(q)' * Y(q);
end

% the update
W = ((1 - eta_t*lambda) * W) + (eta_t * temp / k);

% optional projection step
W = min(1, (1 / sqrt(lambda)) / norm(W) )*W;

disp(['iter', num2str(t)]);

end
```

I commented in the code which I think is enough to understand the meaning of each line. And for the algorithm, refer to Fig.2 of the paper given. And the result after training is this.

[image]

Sometimes the result is even worse. Where did I go wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why did you not cross validate? What do you mean by worse results? You mean less accurate?